# Specify the "rule flow" in a BRMS .bpmn

Tags: drools, jbpm, rule-engine, kie

I'm currently not able to set up a .bpmn file with tasks that references a rule-flow. Can you give me an help ?

This is what I did.

- I've installed RHDS.
- I created a new .bpmn file

But, I don't get where I can set the rule flow for the task.

As usually, an image is worth a thousand words.

[image: my dektop running Red Hat Developer Studio 8]

- as you can see on the top left corner I'm indeed using RH JBoss DS
- I created a rule file and a bpmn file, you can see them in the package explorer on the right.
- I dragged a "business rule task" from the right hand side palette to the process editor in the middle.
- The bottom panel shows the properties of the "business rule task"

The problem is that I don't find any way to specify a "rule flow" for that "business rule task". Any advice about where to set it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sometimes happens, just writing the question makes you think about new ways in which you can solve your problem.

Fact is that in RHDS there are different editors that can edit `.bpmn` files. One of them is "BPMN process editor". If you take care in opening the file with that editor (instead of Bpmn2 Diagram Editor), you'll see another property editor that allows you to set up the "rule-flow".

[image: This is the correct editor to edit the rule flow]

Here, you see that it is possible to edit the rule flow!

[image: the rule flow can be edited]

And obviously, now I know where I can edit directly in the xml.

```
<businessRuleTask id="BusinessRuleTask_4" name="group1" g:ruleFlowGroup="group1flow" >
    <ioSpecification>
    [...]
</businessRuleTask>
```

That's the xml namespace...

```
xmlns:g="http://www.jboss.org/drools/flow/gpd"
```